# Getting html data from another website and caching + is it possible as end user?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, file-get-contents

I have the following code in wordpress which grabs the HTML code for a menu on a shop so the blog and shop (which is a completely different system) have the same dynamic menu, however it takes a while to load, is the code inefficient or do I need to go down the caching route?

```
                <?php
                $url = 'http://localhost:8080/mystore/';
                $content = file_get_contents($url);
                $first_step = explode( '<nav class="top">' , $content );
                $second_step = explode("</nav>" , $first_step[1] );
                echo $second_step[0];
                ?>
```

My other question is that ideally I would like to include a login/my account link from the shop on the blog too, however on the shop this is session based, is there any code like the above which takes into account the end users session? Like maybe loading the external link on behalf of the end user to get the contents (as the users session on the shop will be active)

Answer (score 1):

I response to your first question, depending on how often the menu changes, you could consider caching the HTML using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). Your example would look something like this:

```
<?php
    if ( false === ( $content = get_transient( 'shop_menu_html' ) ) ) {
        // Transient is not present or has expired, so set it
        $url = 'www.externalurl.com';
        $content = file_get_contents( $url );
        set_transient( 'shop_menu_html', $content, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }
    $first_step = explode( '<nav class="top">' , $content );
    $second_step = explode("</nav>" , $first_step[1] );
    echo $second_step[0];
?>
```

Comment: Just to check,is this how I'd do that?

<?php

if ( false === ( $special_query_results = get_transient( 'special_query_results' ) ) ) {

     $special_query_results = $second_step[0];
     set_transient( 'special_query_results', $special_query_results, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}

     $url = 'www.externalurl.com';
     $content = file_get_contents($url);
     $first_step = explode( '<nav class="top">' , $content );
     $second_step = explode("</nav>" , $first_step[1] );
     echo $second_step[0];
?>

Comment: @6h8j5 I have updated my answer with some example code which should do what you need it to.